# Microsoft excel display generated CSV field wrong

Tags: excel, csv, format, date-format

I am not sure I can ask this below question here.

I generated a CSV file. Each CSV line contains a field in this format **{digits}-{digits}** such as **4-48, 5-62**, ...

When I open the CSV file using Microsoft Excel. I got **Apr-48 ( for 4-48)** and **May-62 (for 5-62)**

Anyone has any ideas? I expected what I can see in excel is 4-48, 5-62. I already tried to format the column already. I used general format OR Text format but It didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: @PA: I tried to format the column already. I used general OR Text but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the csv into Excel from `Data > From Text` then go through the wizard and import the columns as text (on step 3 of the wizard) and then excel should not try and be "clever" and covert them to a date.

Comment: This is right answer. I am not good at Excel. Thank you so much!